# IniReadValue method returns empty string

Tags: c#, ini, string

I've been programming using 'Ini.cs' class, that allows me to easily read and write values to ini files, which is useful for basic databases.

Sample part of my playerdata.ini file:

> [ktosthet]
>
> money=550
>
> house=0
>
> lastbonus=2014-06-07
>
> bonuslevel=0

Section name is player's nickname, then there goes money, number of house, last daily bonus, and daily bonus level. To read money from ini file I'm using this:

```
public int cash(string nick)
{
if (haveAccount(nick))
{
return int.Parse(playerdata.IniReadValue(nick, "money"));
}
return 0;
}
```

playerdata is my ini file, nick is section and money is key. It should return int 550, but it appears that string value money is empty.

If I try to get value from other point in code, from any ini file, it works. But in this case, it doesn't. Path is good, ini files are initialized, and everything's good. Any ideas why this won't work?

Ini.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Ini
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a New INI file to store or load data
    /// </summary>
    public class IniFile
    {
        public string path;

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val, string filePath);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);

        /// <summary>
        /// INIFile Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="INIPath"></param>
        public IniFile(string INIPath)
        {
            path = INIPath;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Write Data to the INI File
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Section"></param>
        /// Section name
        /// <param name="Key"></param>
        /// Key Name
        /// <param name="Value"></param>
        /// Value Name
        public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read Data Value From the Ini File
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Section"></param>
        /// <param name="Key"></param>
        /// <param name="Path"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
            return temp.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Here's playerdata:

```
IniFile playerdata;
public string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace("City.EXE", "");
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
playerdata = new IniFile(path + "/paths/playerdata.ini");
}
```

Comment: So you have a global variable called `playerdata` that we don't know anything about it and a `ini.cs` file that contains a class that we don't know anything about. I suggest to add the code of that class and how do you initialize the global variable. (Or better  check with a debugger why the call fails)

Comment: Alright, added @Steve

Comment: AFAIK nothing is clarly wrong here. I suggest to use the debugger and check if the value passed to the call are correct.

Comment: I used debugger, and all values are correct. @Steve

Comment: Sorry, but I have tried your code and I have no problems to read that value. So perhaps there is something on your side. Are you sure about the path? It seems a bit strange the initial replace. And don't forget that the CurrentDirectory could be changed inadvertently by your own code (for example during a FileOpenDialog/FileSaveDialog operation)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I randomly found the answer: section couldn't be first line in the file. Don't know why, but it works now, so who cares.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem earlier. Then I changed 'Copy to output Directory' to 'Copy always' under properties of .ini file. This worked.